# Grade 10 Upper and Lower Bounds Question GCSE

Tags: inequality, rounding-error

I am a student and I need help on a question on upper and lower bounds. I don't know how to work out the handspan.

Ravina measured her handspan with a ruler and found it was 15cm to the nearest centimetre. Angelina measured her handspan more accurately and found it was 148mm to the nearest millimetre.

Use the upper and lower bounds of the measurement to show whether it is possible that Angelina's handspan is larger than Ravina's.

I found out that 148mm is 14.8cm. I don't know what to do next...

Thank you and help would be appreciated

Comment: You asked a harder question yesterday about upper and lower bounds. You say you understood the answer. Use what you learned there about upper bounds to think about this question.

Comment: The highest possible value of a number that is rounded

Answer (score 0):

Hint. What's the largest possible span for Angelina? The smallest for Ravenna?

(By the way, I don't think this is a realistic question. You couldn't really measure Angelina's span to within a millimeter with a ruler.)

Comment: 15.5cm for angelica and 14.75 for Ravena

Comment: This shows that it is possible for Ravens to have a hand span as small as 14.75cm  and angelica is possible to have a hand span as large as 15.5cm.

Comment: Thankyou I now understand the question